# vscode: Move Go code (type/function) to other file

Tags: go, visual-studio-code

How to move a function/type from one Go file to an other Go file in vscode?

... and the IDE should update all usages of the moved function/type ...

In the past I used Python and PyCharm, and it supported this kind of refactoring.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that this feature (the move-refactoring) hasn't been implemented in VSCode yet. The only workaround that just came into my mind is this.
You can use the cmd `gomvpkg` to move a package to a new one. Thanks to this, if you have only the function within the file you should be good to go. It should also update the `import` statements (make sure to double-check them anyway). I know that it's boring in fact I keep copying/pasting functions between packages as it's faster.

> It seems that this feature is already supported in Goland, so you can give it a try maybe if you wish.

Let me know!